# UDP Socketserver - send data through same socket (impossible?)

Tags: python, sockets, udp, request

I have a computer that may be behind several firewalls, have only a private IP... pretty much not reachable from the outside world.

That computer periodically sends UDP data to a remote server (accessible from everywhere). That remote server will probably be in a different network than the UDP sender/client (or in a different country from that matter).

At a certain point, I have to send a package acknowledging that I received some data back to the "unreachable" computer, meaning: the client started a communication and I do have a socket.

I am afraid of the answer, because of what I read of the UDP protocol being mainly *send-->disconnect-->forget about the package*, but here goes the question. Is there any way of sending data using an existing UDP socket?

As a server, I'm using a very simple SocketServer class:

```
class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        message_type = message_utils.extract_type(self.request[0])
        message_cls = message_factory.get_class_by_message_type(message_type)
        message = message_cls(
                              data=self.request[0],
                              came_from=self.client_address)
        print "Got %s" % message
        message.process()
        self.request[1].send("test") 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER_HOST = settings.SERVER_HOST\
                        if hasattr(settings, "SERVER_HOST") else ""
    SERVER_PORT = int(settings.SERVER_PORT)
    server = SocketServer.UDPServer(
                                    (SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT),
                                    MyUDPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

The line `self.request[1].send("test")` is failing with an error: `[Errno 89] Destination address required` and the more I read about it, the more I think I won't be able to send data back to the client, at least not with this simple "`send`" solution.

I can not change the client. Is there ANY way to send UDP data reusing a socket? Maybe there's a "savior" class out there I don't know about? Any hint will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am guessing that this issue is related to the fact that UDP is a connectionless protocol.  I'm not sure a wrapper class will change that.

Comment: Yep... that's exactly what I meant by *I am afraid of the answer* :( I guess I'm hoping for some magic. Thank you for reading the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `.sendto()`, not `.send()`, like this:

```
self.request[1].sendto(
  "test",
  self.client_address)
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-udpserver-example

---

#### Extras:

The smallest responsive UDP socket server than I can create it this:

```
import SocketServer
class MyUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.request[1].sendto( "test\n", self.client_address)
SocketServer.UDPServer( ("", 5432), MyUDPHandler).serve_forever()
```

It can tested from a Linux command line thusly:

```
$ nc -u 127.1 5432
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Although from the client and server perspective, UDP is connectionless, from the NAT/router's perspective, there is a connection that is maintained for two way communication.  The server just needs to reply to the IP/port that it received the message from to reach the client.

The python doc has a good example of this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-udpserver-example

Basically it just needs the request address and use the sendto function

```
socket.sendto("test", self.client_address)
```